# Best way to tell the UITableView which data should be display in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm new to Swift and I followed some tutorials.
They are showing how you are suppose to use a UITableView by using a UITableViewController.
The data displayed in the UITableView are stored in an Array inside the UITableViewController.
I'm OK with it.

Based on this, I tried to make a UITableView with two arrays :

```
struct Spending {
    var title: String
    var amount: Float
    var date: Date?
 }

class TableViewControllerSpending: UITableViewController, SpendingProtocol {
        var spendingsTemporary : [Spending] = [Spending(title: "Shoes", amount: 245.99, date: Date())]
        var spendingsPermanent : [Spending] = [Spending(title: "Taxes", amount: 125.50, date: Date())]
}
```

I would like to use 2 arrays to display both of them depending on the navigation. For instance, when you click on a button "My permanent spending" the UITableView only shows the 'permanent' array data or if you click on "All my spending" you can see the content of the 2 arrays.

What is the best solution to do tell the UITableView which data should be display ?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the flow? Is the user on some screen with two buttons and you show `TableViewControllerSpending` for either button? Why is the data hardcoded into `TableViewControllerSpending`? Don't you need to access that data throughout your app?

Comment: I wanted to use the same TableView to display all my objects "spending". But this view can be reach through several way. In others words, I looking for a method to make a generic TableView for display "Spending" arrays. I think the best way is to pass the array inside a segue to the TableView. What do you think about this way ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
var isPermanent  = true
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return  isPermanent ? spendingsPermanent.count : spendingsTemporary.count 

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = areaSettTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:CellIdentifier1) as! notifyTableViewCell

   if isPermanent {

  }
  else {

  }

    return cell
}
```

//

Change `isPermanent` according to the clicked button and then

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

**Note** you can create one array and assign it the current array and deal with only one array

Comment: Thank you for your response, this work perfectly. Your note is important because I think it's the best solution for me. Like I said in comment, I wanted to make a generic TableView working around an array of "Spending". Is this a good solution ? : Create only one array (ArrayA) in TableViewController. When I call the TableView somewhere in my navigation, I push the array I wanted to display (ArrayB) via segue. When the TVC is loading, I force ArrayA with ArrayB and then "tableView.reloadData()".

Comment: Yes it a good generic approach , make it only one array and supply the content to it during the segue , then it will be loaded with that data

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the best solution is to make `TableViewControllerSpending` a generic view controller that can render a provided array of `Spending` objects.

```
class TableViewControllerSpending: UITableViewController, SpendingProtocol {
    var spendings = [Spending]()
}
```

Implement all of the normal table view methods based on the `spendings` array.

In some appropriate `prepareSegue` method called from the two buttons, you get access to the `TableViewControllerSpending` as the destination controller and then based on the button that was tapped, you set the `spendings` property with one of the two main lists of `Spendings` that you have.

With this approach your `TableViewControllerSpending` has no knowledge that there are two separate lists of data. It just knows how to show a list.